# Discrepancy between CPLEX interface solution and C API

Tags: cplex, modeling-languages, api

I have a C API program uploaded here in [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qen96t54eon3x0h/AAA_Oco9TLVE4_EfErBrSfqta?dl=0) that is an LP. Here is the problem: When I compile the C file it gives me "1017 Not available for mixed-integer problems" while the problem is apparently LP. At the same time, when it prints its solution, it is integer. However, when I write the lp in a .lp file and solve it with CPLEX terminal, it gives the right solution.

Comment: Can you identify which line in the C file generates the 1017 error?

Comment: @prubin: This is a small block of a larger callback program. BTW, this is so strange, I never faced something like this. Even in my larger code, I am not able to solve this part as a linear programming. The interesting part is when I change type of variables to integer and use mipopt instead of lpopt. No error at all.

Comment: Presumably, you don't have my error! line 2302.

Comment: I don't use C, so I can't run your code. Line 2302 is a print statement, so that's an unlikely location for the error to occur.

Comment: I can provide my makefile if it works for you. Definitely, the error refers to line 2295 (CPXlpopt). Here is the point: even CPXgetprobtype returns MILP, while there is no integer/binary variable in the problem.

Comment: Beats me. You might try bisection. Comment out parts of the code and see if what is left is treated as an LP. If yes, the problem is in the commented section; if no, the problem is somewhere else (or both in the commented part and elsewhere). Eventually this should let you identify where the type shifts. Also, I see you are calling CPXgetprobtype, which the docs say is for mixed integer or barrier users only. I would not expect calling it to change the problem type to mixed integer, but who knows?

Comment: Much appreciated! I am very much familiar with debugging and memory management tools and I write very complex codes with CPLEX. I did all, I couldn't find any trace. There are memory leaks in this code but not really relevant that much. About CPXgetprobtype, my C API doc says it gives back problem type. CPXsetprobtype changes the problem type to desirable one though.

Comment: By CPXsetprobtype I meant CPXchgprobtype.